# Imbalance Data For Classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, graphlab

I am having a Data set consist of around `10^6` entries. But the problem is data is `Imbalance`.

I creating a linear classifier using Adboost. But due to imbalance data my accuracy is very poor. How to cop with Imbalance Data. I am using `Graphlab`.

Here is simple  code for balancing of Data:

```
safe_loans_raw = loans[loans[target] == 1]
risky_loans_raw = loans[loans[target] == -1]

# Undersample the safe loans.
percentage = len(risky_loans_raw)/float(len(safe_loans_raw))
safe_loans = safe_loans_raw.sample(percentage, seed = 1)
risky_loans = risky_loans_raw
loans_data = risky_loans.append(safe_loans)
```

But the accuracy is still not approving can anyone provide efficient approach for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Handling the imbalanced data is one of the most challenging fields in the data mining and machine learning domains. Therefore, you will not find a simple, straight answer your question right away.

In my experience using penalized (or weighted) evaluation metrics is one of the best ways (SHORT ANSWER), however (always there is a but!), you can refer the following resources to find the effective approach. Your problem is more of a scientific issue rather than an issue with the tool.

[This](https://github.com/turi-code/tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/intro-regression.ipynb) should handle the situation but make sure that you know the background before using it.

[Free](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

[Not Free but more valuable](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=imbalanced%20data)

Comment: Could you please answer this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32812/categorization-of-approaches-to-deal-with-imbalanced-classes Thanks. @mok

Answer (score 1):

How did you come to a conclusion that the poor accuracy is because of the imbalance of data? Because based on the code that you have provided,`loans_data` should have balanced data(50% risky loans and 50% safe loans approximately). Please check the number of risky loans and safe loans after creating `loans_data` to confirm.

The poor accuracy could be because of the features that you have selected for training your model or the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the paramter `"class_weights="auto"` in boosted trees, which takes care of imbalanced data to a certain extent. For more information, have a look at this : [default paramters](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.boosted_trees_classifier.create.html#graphlab.boosted_trees_classifier.create)